# Python netmiko mudlue import error in python 2.6

Tags: python, multiprocessing, importerror

Hi I have installed netmiko in my python lib and tried to import it.

when i tried it i am getting the below error. pls suggest to resolve this issue.

```
 Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)
 [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import multiprocessing
 >>> import netmiko
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "netmiko/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
   log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler()) # noqa
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NullHandler'
```

Comment: `NullHandler` was not in the source code until 2.7, please use that link above ^^

Comment: thanks for the solution :)

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you still using python 2.6?

Comment: JLT :) i am using old version of linux server. It has python2.6 installed in it. So I thought of working on it without upgrading :)